# In the training of a Deep Learning model, does it matter the sequential order of elements in my dataset I use to input?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, lstm

To be more specific, I’m dealing with a NLP problem and training a LSTM to word prediction given a initial sequence of words. My dataset is 200k reddit comments.

Does it matter if I **randomly feed the examples one at a time** (allowing repeated inputs) or if I feed them in a **sequence** (not allowing repetitions)?

Comment: what is an example here? A word? Or the whole sequence?

Comment: an example is an entire comment, a sequence of words.

Comment: depends on the task. what exactly is the task?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is actually a set of comments, there is no need to process them in a sequence. In fact, typically it is better to process data in random order to make sure that network does not learn something which is order dependent. Repeats do not matter at all, as long as you sample uniformly.